# Infinite recursion issue with Json object (using Java/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, java, json, mirth

I'm using Javascript/Java to query an MSSQL database, and then use the CachedRowSet received from the query to add some information to a Json object. Here's the code that's querying the database and adding the results to the object.

```
var sqlGetVariables = "SELECT MappingVariable.Id as Id, MappingVariable.Name AS Name, MappingVariable.Value AS Value FROM MappingGroup LEFT JOIN MappingVariable ON MappingGroup.Id = MappingVariable.MappingGroupId WHERE MappingGroup.Id = " + mappingGroupId + " AND MappingVariable.Id IS NOT NULL";
var resultVariables = uberfaceDB.executeCachedQuery(sqlGetVariables);

while (resultVariables.next()) {
    var variableId = resultVariables.getObject("Id");
    var variableName = resultVariables.getObject("Name");
    var variableMapping = resultVariables.getObject("Value");

    jsonArray["Segments"][seg]["Variables"][variableName] = {};
    jsonArray["Segments"][seg]["Variables"][variableName]["Mapping"] = variableMapping;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that there's something goofy going on with the last line where I assign "variableMapping" to the Json object. The line of code executes just fine, but when I go to iterate through the Json object later, I get stuck in an infinite recursion that keeps cycling through "class" "package" and "specificationversion".

Here's the code I'm using to iterate through the object.

```
function echoJson (jsonArray, strStuff) {
    var strJson = "" + strStuff;

    for (var item in jsonArray) {
        logger.error(strJson + " --> " + item);
        echoJson(jsonArray[item], strJson + " --> " + item);
    }
}
```

The logger.error function is built in to the application I'm coding in (called Mirth Connect). It simply outputs the message to a console for error/debugging purposes. Here's an example of what I would EXPECT to get with the echoJson function:

> Segments --> MSH --> Segments --> PID --> Variables --> PatientFirstName --> Mapping --> variableMappingValue

But here's what I'm actually getting:

> Segments --> MSH --> Segments --> PID --> Variables --> PatientFirstName --> Mapping --> class --> package --> specificationVersion --> class --> package --> specificationVersion --> class --> package --> specificationVersion...

It continues repeating the "class --> package --> specificationVersion" portion infinitely until I stop the application.

If I replace the following line of code:

```
jsonArray["Segments"][seg]["Variables"][variableName]["Mapping"] = variableMapping;
```

With a hard coded string, like

```
jsonArray["Segments"][seg]["Variables"][variableName]["Mapping"] = "test";
```

Then it works without any problems.

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this!!

Comment: Why is this tagged java? And shouldn't it be tagged with whatever javascript library you're using to access the database?

Comment: It's tagged Java because, as per my comments above, there is some Java utilized. While most of it is behind the scenes in the database calls, one of the primary components in my issue is Java's CachedRowSet, which is what the SQL results are stored in (the resultVariables object). As for adding the library, I've added Mirth, which is the software I'm doing this coding in. It has it's own proprietary javascript library that is kind of a top layer over other Java libraries, though I don't know which ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, as explained on [another programmer's blog](http://nelsonwells.net/2012/02/json-stringify-with-mapped-variables/).

There was an issue with the data type being stored in the CachedRowSet. I don't know the exact data type, but from what I gathered the "variableMapping" variable is a byte array, and I'm needing to add it to my Json object as a string. I had to do "new String(variableMapping)" to convert the array into a string, and that fixed my problem.

How I found the problem: I decided to try using JSON.stringify() to output my Json object, and received the following error:

> Java class "[B" has no public instance field or method named "toJSON"

Googling that led me to the blog post I linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

Your function echoJson is calling itself. This is called recursion. From [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blrecursive.htm), "the first thing when calling a function recursively is that you need to make sure that there is some form of exit condition where the function will not call itself recursively." It appears that your function does not have an exit condition. In other words, before calling echoJson inside echoJson, check first if you ought to.

```
function echoJson (jsonArray, strStuff) {
    var strJson = "" + strStuff;

    for (var item in jsonArray) {
        logger.error(strJson + " --> " + item);
        if (isGoodAndNice(jsonArray[item]))
        echoJson(jsonArray[item], strJson + " --> " + item);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this wasn't what I needed to resolve the root of my issue, this is definitely something I hadn't thought about that I really need to incorporate in my function. Thanks for the info!